# Как из django admin вытащить форму для редактирования модели

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django admin автоматически генерирует формы для редактирования моделей. Я бы хотел эту самую форму применить ещё на одной странице моего сайта. Можно ли как-то получить эту форму?

Comment: открой файлик admin.py и импортни из него форму

Comment: @eri, если несложно, напишите, что для этого нужно прописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Джанго в админке использует модельные формы.
Делается так:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import MyModel


class MyForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Ну и применяете её уже в шаблоне.

Если же вас вёрстка интересует, то это другой разговор.